# PHP secure downloader with PayDotCom or Paypal

Tags: php

The script below is a quick and dirty attempt to provide a means of protecting my files that I'm selling on PayDotCom and Paypal.

If anyone has experience with these services, I have a few questions...

1) Is there a token that I can set at either of these pay sites that I can then check for in the script below before executing the download?

2) In the script below, the file that is retrieved is correct, however, the filename it wants to save it to is the same as the PHP processing page (secure-download.php). How can I change the saved file's filename? e.g. it will be a zip file.

3) There's a few notes in the code below, I need some advice on...

```
<?php

    $file = basename(urldecode($_GET['file']));
    $fileDir = dirname(dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) )."/secure/";

// The secure directory is outside of www root

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
    {
        // Note: Need advice here to do some more checks 
        // on the filetype, size, etc.
        $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . $file);

        // Note: Need to implement some kind 
        // of check on filetype
        header('Content-type: application/zip');

        echo $contents;
                    //currently the filename is same as the processing file, need to change it to [somefile].zip

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy im not sure i understand your uestion but i think you hae a problem with downloading the file? right if so here is your fixed code:

```
<?php

    $file = basename(urldecode($_GET['file']));
    $fileDir = dirname(dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) )."/secure/";

// The secure directory is outside of www root

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents();
        header("Content-Type: x-type/subtype");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\""$fileDir.$file"\"");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps with the filename issue, but I'm getting an error on the content-disposition...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in pathtomyfile on line 12

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with line 12. I'm going to accept your answer and create another one specifically for the IPN/Paypal and PayDotCom question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the filename easily with the following:

header("Content-Disposition: atachment; filename=myfilename.zip");

As for token protecting, you would need to refer to the PayPal documentation, as you'll need this script to have an incoming token variable - then transmit that to them for confirmation it is a valid token.